# Not able to fetch SequenceInformation and not finding Column start_with in ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I am seeing the below error when running a small test program to check that my Hibernate config is correct.  I checked that the sequence for each table has valid settings--the max value is less than Long's MAX_VALUE.  My entity classes use annotation-based configuration and are all listed within my cfg.xml file.  I was able to insert at least one record into each table using pgAdmin, so I know that sequences are working.  This error is occurring when the the program tries to get a SessionFactory

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
//          System.err.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
//          Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
//          Configuration configure = configuration.configure(TypesDaoFt.class.getResource("./hibernate.cfg.xml"));
//          sf = configure.buildSessionFactory();

            StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure(new File("./hibernate.cfg.xml")).build();
            Metadata md = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sf = md.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Failed to build SessionFactory.");
            t.printStackTrace();
            if(sf != null) {
                sf.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

`ERROR: Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name start_with was not found in this ResultSet.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2589)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2485)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at com.javaduckspizza.ftesters.TypesDaoFt.main(TypesDaoFt.java:30)`

Comment: What postgresql, hibernate version and hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Postgresql 12; Hibernate 5.4.11 Final;

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Postgresql 12; Hibernate 5.4.11 Final; org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect.  Sorry, it auto-posted my last response while I was afk.

Comment: Upon further research, it turns out that HSQLDialect is for HyperSQL and HyperSonics, not HQL.  I switched to PostgreSQLDialect, and now it works.  Strange, because I was getting an error message for PostgreSQLDialect that went away after changing.  I must have fixed whatever was causing that error.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong hibernate dialect. The `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` dialect is intended to use with the [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) database.

The `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect` dialect is more suitable for your case.